# Using ansible to execute sql command on psql server

Tags: postgresql, bash, ansible, psql

I have a PostgreSQL server running on a Linux Red Hat VM (installed from rh-postgresql96) and am trying to create a role in the database through the psql shell using the following Ansible task.

```
- name: Setup database
  become_user: postgres
  become: yes
  block:
    - name: Enter psql shell
      shell: |
        scl enable rh-postgresql96 bash      
    - name: Create user1 role
      shell: |
        psql -c "CREATE ROLE user1 WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'pass!123' VALID UNTIL 'infinity';"
```

But when I do this, it just hangs on the psql shell task...
Any ideas?

Please note, I do **not** want to use the postgresql ansible plugin to achieve this.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/postgresql/postgresql_user_module.html#ansible-collections-community-postgresql-postgresql-user-module

Comment: @Zeitounator I do not want to use the postgresql ansible plugin to achieve this.

Comment: I don't get why won't use a module that is made for that and is idempotent. Using `shell` for every task in ansible is not its intended use and you may easily misuse it as I'm pretty sure you did above. I don't know `scl` but I'm quite sure it sets env vars in running shell and/or drops few lines in .bashrc. `shell` is non login/interactive, re-spawns on each run (bye vars!), does not load e.g. .bashrc and uses sh by default. I guess your task hangs waiting for a password. Run both commands at once in the same `shell` task, load needed files yourself, set bash as `shell` binary if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It may probably be waiting for some sort of input such as password. While executing mysql queries with ansible, I used the following format:

```yaml
- name: Set max queries for hour for specified user
  expect:
     command:  mysql -u root -p -e "ALTER USER '{{username}}'@'{{userhost}}' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR {{MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR}};"
     echo: yes
     responses:
        'password': "{{mysql_root_password}}"
```

This query is irrelevant to the topic, but I used expect module to give the password input.

Comment: Please note that, as asked in the question, this is also a bad usage of Ansible as there is a dedicated module for seting MySQL users as well. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_user_module.html